issue with Chrome’s garbage collector
I’ve been facing an issue with Chrome’s garbage collector not clearing nodes that are no longer in use,  even after I manually remove the JavaScript scripts that reference them.
This was working fine in previous Chrome versions, but in the latest version (v.129), the garbage collector seems to be malfunctioning or behaving differently. I tested this with a basic JS script, and it still works as expected in MS Edge for now, but I’m concerned that this might also stop working in their next release.
Has anyone else noticed this change in behavior in Chrome’s GC? I’ve tried using Bootstrap’s dispose() method to manually clean up, im having same issue with other JS scripts also.
Any advice or insights on why Chrome’s GC is no longer handling this correctly would be greatly appreciated.
This is the test script:
function writeHtml() {
    var dynamicDiv = $('#dynamicDiv');
    var selectHtml = `
        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#offcanvasExample" role="button" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
            Link with href
            </a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasExample" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
            Button with data-bs-target
            </button>

            <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasExample" aria-labelledby="offcanvasExampleLabel">
            <div class="offcanvas-header">
                <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasExampleLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="offcanvas-body">
                <div>
                Some text as placeholder. In real life you can have the elements you have chosen. Like, text, images, lists, etc.
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown mt-3">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                    Dropdown button
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    `;
    dynamicDiv.append(selectHtml);
    
}

function destroy() {
    
    disposeBootstrapComponents();
    
    $('#dynamicDiv').empty();
    
    /* Tryed this, doesnt help
    var $dynamicDiv = $('#dynamicDiv');
    $dynamicDiv.empty(); // Empty the contents of dynamicDiv before replacing it

    var $clonedDiv = $dynamicDiv.clone(false);
    $dynamicDiv.replaceWith($clonedDiv);
    dynamicDiv = null;
    clonedDiv = null;

    */

}
 
function disposeBootstrapComponents() {
    $('[data-bs-toggle="dropdown"]').dropdown('dispose');
    $('.offcanvas').offcanvas('dispose');
}

$(document).on('click', '#addButton', function () {
    writeHtml();
});
$(document).on('click', '#destroyButton', function () {
    destroy();
});

detached

Removing a <script> element from the DOM doesn't do anything to the code or data that was loaded by that script.

what is that image supposed to show?

What I was trying to explain was that when I manually destroyed a JS script that referenced an element, the GC should remove that element, but it still remained in memory and wasn't fully removed, even though it was disconnected according to the image I posted. However, in the new version of Chrome, which seems to have been released today, it works as expected: the elements are removed from memory.

@RobZ What do you mean by "I manually destroyed a JS script"?

What new version of Chrome? I just checked for updates and it says I'm up-to-date with 129.0.6668.90.
